# PDF figure not scaled in PDFLaTeX

Tags: graphics, floats, pdftex

I use pdflatex in order to use microtype. However, I have to import pdf figures and not eps.
The problem is that the scale option seems to be ignored because in the pdf file I see the figure in the original size.

```
\documentclass[a4paper,11pt,twoside,showtrim,openright,titlepage]{memoir}
\usepackage{footnote}
\usepackage{graphicx}
% MICROTYPE
\usepackage[tracking=true,letterspace=-10]{microtype}
\usepackage{lmodern}
\DeclareMicrotypeAlias{lmss}{cmr}
\DisableLigatures{encoding = T1, family = tt*}
\SetTracking{shape = sc}{10}
\SetTracking{encoding = *}{100}
\usepackage{hyphenat}

\begin{document}
  \begin{figure*}[th]
    \centering
    \includegraphics[scale=0.20]{foto/Mad1.pdf}
    \thispagestyle{empty}
  \end{figure*}
\end{document}
```

**[EDIT]**

I tried all suggestions, also that in the accepted answer, but I confirm that it does not work. Moreover, the scale option is creepy: the image position is strange and difficult to understand why.

Comment: Your code does not compile. If I add an `\usepackage{graphicx}`, it works and does not show your problem.

Comment: @giuseppe: I wonder that your document is compiled at all using `pdflatex` without using `usepackage{graphicx}`. I used your example, added the above mentioned line exchanged your graphic pdf by one of my files -- it scaled correctly. Perhaps there is something strange in your `Mad1.pdf` file?

Comment: I edited the question, sorry. How can I check if the problem is with the figure? I converted Mad1.eps to Mad1.pdf by using ps2pdf.

Comment: @giuseppe: `ps2pdf` should work but please try `epstopdf` as well. Have you already opened that `Mad1.pdf` with a pdf viewer? Does it show correctly on screen?

Comment: You are master: epstopdf is the right command! Thanks

Comment: @giuseppe: Well, that's fine. I remember that I had a similiar problem some years ago, I think, `ps2pdf` was to blame too.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If an EPS file is converted with `ps2pdf`, the result is usually a PDF file with a full page, because EPS files are not allowed to change the media size. Therefore it is better to use option `-dEPSCrop`:

```
ps2pdf -dEPSCrop Mad1.eps
```

Then ghostscript will look at a comment `%%BoundingBox` to set the media size.
Alternatively, `epstopdf` can be used that does a similar job and calls ghostscript:

```
epstopdf Mad1.eps
```

If the bounding box is not correctly recorded by the comment and white margins are left, then they can be removed with `pdfcrop`:

```
pdfcrop Mad1.pdf
```

The result is `Mad1-crop.pdf`.

At LaTeX level, you can check for white margins by putting the image inside `\fbox`:

```
{\setlength{\fboxsep}{0pt}\fbox{\includegraphics[scale=.2]{Mad1.pdf}}}
```

Comment: I still cannot scale the figure!

Comment: @giuseppe: Which program generated the original `Mad1.eps` file? Please try to make an 'ordinary' `latex` file, include your `Mad1.eps` file and run the 'ordinary' `latex` command on your file, but omit that microtype commands first.

Comment: I used both convert and gimp.

Comment: @giuseppe Am I supposing correctly, that your original file was a photograph stored as `jpg`? If that is true, you could just include the original file-- there is no need of converting to eps and then to `pdf`.